# How can I shorten commands related to Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

To start my Rails app, I go to `/var/www/html/app` dir first.
Then I execute rest of two commands.

```
1. $ cd /var/www/html/app
2. $ bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=production
3. $ unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
```

I want to omit first line. and put it into 2nd, and 3rd command.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the best way to solve this problem is just creating your own shell script. It's pretty easy and useful in many ways.

```
#!/bin/sh
# file-name: app-start.sh
cd /var/www/html/app
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=production
unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
```

then

```
chmod +x app-start.sh
./app-start.sh
```

Comment: it depends. My strategy is I will put it where I find easily, maybe in `~/scripts`, then make a symlink to `/usr/local/bin`, make sure it is included in your $PATH.
then you can call your script everywhere.

Comment: What if I don't use $PATH? Can I still write whole Absolute PATH in shell command? If so, how can I write? Could you give me an example?

Comment: yeah you can do that, for example in my case, I put my scripts in `~/scripts`. Then I can call it like this `~/scripts/app-start.sh`.

Comment: Thanks. Now, if I type `/var/app-start.sh`, it triggers and works everything fine. But still one problem! I did put `/var/app-start.sh` in the end line of `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`. It should fire that on start up of server. But it doesn't work:( Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: ok, in case you put it into another script, you have to  use `sh /var/app-start.sh`.

Comment: I did put `sh /var/app-start.sh` in the end of `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` but it still looks it's not fired:( weird

Comment: hmm, I'm not so familiar with `rc.local` and btw, it's off topic of the current question, so you can open another one, I hope I can help. [ I'm not in Linux now ]

Comment: Thanks that's true. I will open another topic. I'll paste a link to it. So if possible please help me over there:)

Comment: Here's a link to new topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490887/why-this-shell-wont-work-from-rc-local-but-ssh

Answer (score 2):

You could set up an alias to do everything at once.

If you are using Zsh for example, you can add this to `~/.zshrc`:

`alias run_app="cd /var/www/html/app; bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=production; unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D"`

Then now, when you type `run_app` steps 1 to 3 will execute.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to set into `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` so that it automatically execute commands.  I'm not looking for alias.  I just want to know how to shorten my original commands, and how to put into `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` to enable auto-start on Server's start up.

Answer (score 2):

You can chain any number of commands using && operator
`cd /var/www/html/app && bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=production && unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D`

Comment: Thanks:) and can I just paste that whole line into the end of  `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`

Comment: I tried to paste it into the end of `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`, and rebooted. But it seems not working:(

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**foreman**](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) to start and manage these different processes.

1. `$ cd /var/www/html/app`
2. Create a file named `Procfile` with these processes for example:

   web: unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D (line break here, not sure why SO is doing this)
   search: bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=production
3. Start the processes with `foreman start`.

This is what you'd do anyway when hosting your app on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use these commands:

```
/var/www/html/app/bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=production
/var/www/html/app/unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
```