# Why this shell won't work if it's called from rc.local but SSH?

Tags: linux, shell, startup

I made this shell script

**/var/start-app.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
# file-name: app-start.sh
cd /var/www/html/app
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=production
unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
```

If I type `/var/start-app.sh` in SSH. It triggers, and everything works fine.

Then I did put `sh /var/start-app.sh` in the end line of `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` in order to make it run on Server's start up.

But this never work. Why? and How can I enable that?

From SSH, I called it with `root` permission.
Is that why? If so, how can I give root permission to `rc.local`?

Comment: have you ever tried to user `upstart`, the one you are trying to make it work seems to cause you a lot of trouble

Comment: @nXqd What's `upstart` about? I'm suspecting that there's something related to rc.local's User. Is there any possibility that it doesn't have permission to `start-app.sh`? From SSH, I called `start-app.sh` with `root` permission. Is that why it works fine?

Comment: Can help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/239600/why-doesnt-rc-local-run-all-my-commands-and-what-can-i-do-about-it

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks. I took a look at the link. But I couldn't get it what's wrong with my version

Comment: Try first to see if adding it to `rc.local` is working at all. What if you change the script to `echo "hello" > /tmp/test`? If it creates the `/tmp/test` file, then you know it is running the script but something inside it is wrong. Maybe full/relative paths?

Comment: @fedorqui I tried your suggestion. Indeed it created `/tmp/test` file. Then I replaced inside if `start-app.sh` with my orginal shell script. Then now it won't work again:(

Comment: Isn't it something related to User? like root

Comment: Could be. Check the permissions of this script. `rc.local` will be executed by root, so make sure this user can perfectly do it. That is, try to copy the environment in which `rc.local` will execute. What if you use full path on every command / file?

Comment: @fedorqui `urc.local`'s user is `root`. When I succeeded at calling `app-start.sh` from SSH. I do `su` first. and get root permission. Then I execute `/var/start-app.sh`. This works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like starting services from rc.local is not the best practice http://bencane.com/2011/12/30/when-its-ok-and-not-ok-to-use-rc-local/. You would be better writing an init script :
http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/sysinit.html